# rewriterule in htaccess to match certain file extensions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I look for an instance for certain file extensions, like .(jpg|png|css|js|php), and if there is NOT a match send it to index.php?route=$1.

I would like to be able to allow period's for custom usernames.

So, rewrite http://example.com/my.name to index.php?route=my.name

Current setup:

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What works:
http://example.com/userpage -> index.php?route=userpage
http://example.com/userpage/photos -> index.php?route=userpage/photos
http://example.com/file.js -> http://example.com/file.js
http://example.com/css/file.css -> http://example.com/css/file.css

What I need to work in addition to above:
http://example.com/my.name -> index.php?route=my.name

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add an extra RewriteCond to exclude the conditions that you don't want rewritten. Use a `!` before the regular expression to indicate that any files matching should fail the condition. The RewriteCond below is untested, but should give you an idea of what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$
```

Comment: Combine this with _allowing_ a dot in names/routes (so, replacing `[^.]` with `.` in the original `RewriteRule` from your question). A.t.m, you forcefully don't allow a dot there, so of course it's not going to work.

Comment: Ah, you are right Wrikken. Modified the rule and it came together. I really appreciate the help guys

Comment: @nbrogi  no, as there is the 'end of line' symbol : $ to say it has to end with the extension.

Comment: note that you should also allow .ico for your favicon and .txt for robots.txt . Si add these rewritecond : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico$

Comment: the best think to use here I think is ^(.*)$ instead of ^([^.]+)$

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried reversing the logic? Something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|css|js)$ - [L]
```

This will not do a rewrite for any file with a .jpg, .png, .css, or .js extension. Then add your existing rules so that non-file, non-directory requests get rerouted to index.php.

Comment: just remember that -f is terrible slow in high load environments as this requires a filesystem access. checkin `REQUEST_URI` is much faster!