# .htaccess rewrite URL parameters AND remove PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to put together a .htaccess file to do the following:

1) rewrite URL params from the from:

```
 www.domain.com/page.php?key0=val0&key1=val1 ...
```

to

```
www.domain.com/page.php/key0/val0/key1/val1 ...
```

2) Remove the .php extension so
     `www.domain.com/page.php` becomes `www.domain.com/page`

The end result should be:

```
www.domain.com/page/key0/val0/key1/val1 ...
```

I've pieced together this .htaccess and it satisfies 1) and 2) but it has problems.

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 400 /book/ServiceUnavailable
ErrorDocument 401 /book/ServiceUnavailable
ErrorDocument 404 /book/PageNotFound
ErrorDocument 500 /book/ServiceUnavailable

#change homepage /directory
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm

#enable gzip compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*?)/?$ $1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC] [QSA] [L]
```

The 2 problems it has:

a) I get 404 errors on some images and also on included javascript files.  i include js files directly referencing them from doc root, but I get a 404 error: `GET http://localhost/book/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js 404 (Not Found)`

b) When I type a slash at the end of a URL i get a 'Internal Server Error' error:  e.g. `www.domain.com/page/`  causes internal server error.

Can someone help me with a), possibly by adjusting my rules to exclude files that are .js, .png, .jpg, etc and also fix problem b)?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be better off having a PHP file as a `router` which would handle all the requests... Just route everything that's not a file or directory to index.php and go from there.

Comment: I think you need to escape that trailing slash; so `\/?` instead of `/?`

Comment: Good to hear. What do you mean by reference/include? "I include file1.js, file1.js references file2.js" ...there's no direct include construct for javascript. It's not like PHP.

Comment: @acobster  You're right.  I was sloppy - I am getting the 404 error on the JS files I include directly from doc root.  I updated my question to reflex this

Comment: This explains how to fail a rule based on file extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038079/rewriterule-in-htaccess-to-match-certain-file-extensions

Comment: Another great find and it worked - One bug though - My URL, when it takes URL parameters it expects key value pairs.  However, if i skip a key or value, I get an internal server error: e.g. this works: www.mydomain.com/page?key0/val0/key1/val1 but this causes error: www.mydomain.com/page?key0/val0/key1

Comment: all those
 %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$
is a bad idea in my opinion...
all you need is 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
and then you can hide your php code inside some directory protected from direct access, and in addition protect it with some constant and check whether it is defined or not...
Like it is done in some of the modern frameworks.

If it will be accessed directly you can show 404 error...

Comment: @DavidConstantine can you please share a link showing how this is done?

Comment: I think the best way to go is to look at some framework like code igniter.
Take a look at how files are protected there...
And how the routing is done.